# Ruby gem environment's shell path different than the shell path

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've installed [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) and gem and use [bundle](http://bundler.io/). But when I try to install from a Gemfile it fails:

```
> which bundle                                                                                                                                                                              
/opt/local/bin/bundle
> bundle install                                                                                                                                                                            
Your Ruby version is 2.1.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.3
```

The Gemfile specified `ruby '2.1.3'` which is what I have installed locally:

```
> rbenv local
2.1.3
> rbenv global
2.1.3
> ruby -v                                                                                                                                                                                   
ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
> which ruby                                                                                                                                                                                
/path/to/home/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

This all seems good so far. The system ruby is 2.1.7.

My shell search path `$PATH` starts with the shims `/path/to/home/.rbenv/shims:`. However, when I dump the `gem environment` then that shell path has more entries *before* the shims, one of which contains the system ruby:

```
> echo $PATH                                                                                                                                                                                
/path/to/home/.rbenv/shims: ...
> which gem                                                                                                                                                                                 
/path/to/home/.rbenv/shims/gem
> gem environment                                                                                                                                                                           
  ...
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /path/to/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin
     - /opt/local/bin                <- contains system ruby 2.1.7 
     - /path/to/home/.rbenv/shims    <- $PATH starts here
     - ... standard $PATH continues
```

I suspect that this is why installing from a given Gemfile keeps failing. Is there a proper way to modify the gem's shell path, or where does this expanded path originate?

Comment: which gem; which bundle (i.e. where is gem and bundle picked up from. going to guess this is system and that pulls in system ruby)

Comment: `gem` is a local shim from the same folder as the local `ruby`. The `bundle` is global. I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it the global bundler that is referencing the global ruby. You need to do:

```
gem install bundler
rbenv rehash
```

See http://dan.carley.co/blog/2012/02/07/rbenv-and-bundler/ for an explanation on what's going on.